# How to protect a website with authorization without a user signing in?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, authorization, owin

The scenario is that **a signed in user** prepares some material and dispatches it to a number of email addresses. In each email, there's a link to the webpage where they visitors can read about something and leave suggestions.

Since I can't request the visitors to register themselves, the pages to be visited are exposed without any authorization. One requires a valid guid to hit the existing page, though.

My question is if there's a good method to provide authorization of **users not signed in**. Is the guid token sent out to their email accounts the best protection I can offer, given that they can't be bothered to sign in manually themselves?

I rejected the idea of tracking IP numbers since I can't guarantee that they won't be accessing the website from different locations.

Comment: If you need to know which of the users accessed the document you could create and store a guid per email address and create a personalized link per email sent. Both this and your current scheme is insecure in that anyone who gets hold of the link would be able to access the content without any challenge besides the link itself.

Comment: If a resource needs authorization for "private" access then it needs it. Some "unique string", unless "one time" (or some expiration) won't do anything. One can simply share that link anywhere..making it "public". Perhaps using an external "authority" (Facebook, Google, Paypal, etc.) login will make it "easier" for the end user(?) - no _additional_ registration (obviously must if no account on any of them). Hth..

Comment: @user469104 I'm generating a unique guids for each sent email, so your suggestions is on par with my approach (great minds think alike, eh?). However, while I can live with a user sharing the link with someone else, I'm sure that in my particular case, they won't, as it's to their heavy disadvantage. My concern is mainly that someone else **might guess** the guid and I'm looking for a more intricate method of making it extra hard.

Comment: @KonradViltersten here is a good answer related to odds of 'guessing' a GUID, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878359/what-is-the-probability-of-guessing-matching-a-guid. From the answer, "To have a 50% chance of guessing g, our attacker would have to generate 2^127 GUIDs. At a rate of one billion per second, it would take 5391448762278159040348 years to generate 2^127 GUIDs". So from a strict 'security through obscurity' point of view, GUIDs are pretty good :)

Comment: @user469104 Yeah, I felt that way too - a lot of combos to guess. I just wanted to verify with the community to make sure. Now, without attempting to contradict your point (which I agree with), I need to point out that there's flaw in the calculation, because it assumes that there's a single guid that is targeted. In reality, my DB might have gazillions of guids and hitting **any** of them might be much more likely than hitting a single or specific one. That being said, I don't have that many guids exposed and the information isn't very sensitive, so your point's still valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Shared Access Signature](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1/) approach. Azure uses that for getting the access for the Storage (with the policies like an expiration time, etc), OneDrive uses similar approach for sharing the files, etc. 
I think that (you mentioned Azure) you can even use the Azure Storage SAS mechanisms for that. Without expiration and other policies and just a GUID, i believe, is not ideal solution.

Answer (score 1):

I guess user will open  the link in the default browser for most. Than there is a js library [Fingerprint](https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2) which allows to identify user unique browser instance. You can inject this library into target webpage which users will visit from their email client(by clicking on the link). So storing guid plus user fingerprint can  provide some simple "authorization".

In general store guid and email where this guid was sent is more generic solution. But not so secured as anyone can steal guid and use for impersonation.