# Amazon S3 Privacy & Security

Tags: security, amazon-s3, privacy

We are storing files uploaded by users of our app to Amazon S3.

In order to keep these files private & secure, we are:

1. having the client generate a UUID for the filename (so that the URL of the file is difficult to guess). See: [What is the probability of guessing (matching) a Guid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878359/what-is-the-probability-of-guessing-matching-a-guid)
2. going to [protect the data by using client-side encryption](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingClientSideEncryption.html).

Do these two measures provide sufficient security, or should we also use Amazon Cognito to ensure that the user getting the object is one of the users who has access to it?

Comment: How are they accessing the files? For instance, are they making direct api calls to S3 to download the files?

Comment: The users access the files through the client's user interface, and the client makes the API calls to S3.

Comment: How do you grant permissions? Can any client access any folder in the bucket? Is the bucket open to "Everyone"?

Comment: Yes, the bucket is open to everyone, but the only allowed actions are `s3:GetObject` & `s3:PutObject`.

Comment: if bucket has putobject permission, is it possible to corrupt other users files?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to overwrite any file, if you specify its URL.

Comment: @mattdipasquale so, we can loop over all possible uuids and upload empty file (via botnet of course)?

Comment: @Lashane I think so, although I don't know if Amazon S3 protects against something like that, since it sounds similar to a DoS attack, and I imagine they protect against that.

Comment: @Lashane do you think that would be viable? With the birthday paradox, in order to generate a 50% chance of one collision 2.71 quintillion uuids would need to be generated.

Comment: @mattdipasquale so, are users aware that their files can be corrupted by 3rd party?

Comment: @PrestonM will you use this app with such security hole?

Comment: @Lashane well, we haven't released this yet, but I guess we could add something to the privacy policy if we only took measures 1 & 2.

Comment: @mattdipasquale ok, 2nd question - what credentials are used to connect to s3? are they stored in application itself? what if you need to change them immediately?

Comment: @Lashane well, we could use [Amazon S3 Versioning to prevent users from overwriting the original file that was uploaded](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=332871).

Comment: @mattdipasquale you cannot use versioning to _prevent_ overwriting

Comment: @Lashane no credentials are needed. Everyone can make `getObject` & `putObject` API calls to the S3 bucket.

Comment: @mattdipasquale awesome! I need to save my video archive somewhere, will you continue to pay for this bucket?

Comment: @Lashane I think we could set a max size per file. Also, we could run a cron job every so often that checks for dangling files (those not referenced by the database) and delete them.

Comment: @mattdipasquale you're missing my point - model you've described is very fragile, you should re-architect your app, don't try to fix thing which is broken from the very beginning

Comment: Amazon S3 versioning will keep the original version of the file, and the client could always show that one and ignore any newer versions.

Answer (score 1):

Using obscure filenames is not a good security method.

If you wish to allow users to upload/download data to/from Amazon S3 in a secure manner, you should use [Pre-Signed URLs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html).

The process is:

- Users authenticate to your web/mobile application
- Users interact with your application and indicate they wish to upload/download a file
- Your application generates a pre-signed URL that includes an authorization to access Amazon S3, with restrictions such as bucket, path and file size
- Users upload/download the file using the pre-signed URL

This way, your application controls the security and there is no potential for accidental workaround, overwriting, access, etc.

See: [Uploading Objects Using Pre-Signed URLs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html)